# NodeMCU esp8266 keeps disconnecting my laptop from the router

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have done the home automation thing in my house. Everything goes well but every time when I switch on my nodemcu **esp8266** it disconnects my laptop from my home wifi and sometimes my laptop stuck and doesn't reconnect. And it happens only with laptop rest of the devices remain connected.

Here is the code which I have used

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

/* Put your SSID & Password */
const char* ssid = "***";
const char* password = "***";


ESP8266WebServer server(80);

int ledPin1 = 5; // GPIO5 D1
int ledPin2 = 4; // GPIO4 D2
int ledPin5 = 14; // D5
int ledPin6 = 12; // D6

void handle_Led1(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin1, !digitalRead(ledPin1));
  String mess = String(digitalRead(ledPin1)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin2)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin5)) +"," + String(digitalRead(ledPin6));
  server.send(200, "text/plain", mess); 
}

void handle_Led2(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, !digitalRead(ledPin2));
  String mess = String(digitalRead(ledPin1)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin2)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin5)) +"," + String(digitalRead(ledPin6));
  server.send(200, "text/plain", mess); 
}

void handle_Led5(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin5, !digitalRead(ledPin5));
  String mess = String(digitalRead(ledPin1)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin2)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin5)) +"," + String(digitalRead(ledPin6));
  server.send(200, "text/plain", mess); 
}
void handle_Led6(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin6, !digitalRead(ledPin6));
  String mess = String(digitalRead(ledPin1)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin2)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin5)) +"," + String(digitalRead(ledPin6));
    server.send(200, "text/plain", mess); 
}
void handle_OnCheck() {
  String mess = String(digitalRead(ledPin1)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin2)) + "," + String(digitalRead(ledPin5)) +"," + String(digitalRead(ledPin6));
  server.send(200, "text/plain", mess); 
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin6, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin1, 0);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, 0);
  digitalWrite(ledPin5, 0);
  digitalWrite(ledPin6, 0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
  }
  
  server.on("/check", handle_OnCheck);
  server.on("/LED1", handle_Led1);
  server.on("/LED2", handle_Led2);
  server.on("/LED5", handle_Led5);
  server.on("/LED6", handle_Led6);
  
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();

}
```

Comment: So, what does handle_client do? You sent the code for handle_led and handle_notfound, but I don't see handle_client. Furthermore don't have any time steering in handle_client (such as difference of millis between the executions or in worst case a delay) this action will be performed extremely often in a very short time... However, I don't see any reason why only the laptop looses connection. Did you check the IP of your ESP and of the Notebook? And the IP ranke in your router? Maybe the available IPs are exceeded?

Comment: @Tyron78 Thanks for giving me time. I think handleClient() checks for the get requests that are sent from the client that are described in server.on().  And time steering, please can you suggest which value should I give.      subnet mask - 255.255.255.0 notebook-IP - 192.168.29.235 espIP           - 192.168.29.114

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had flashed a code having AP mode with the same name of my home wifi which was confusing my notebook which network is what.

And uploading new code was not removing the previous one as it was just overwriting the space it has in the memory.

So I flashed empty file to esp8266 using esptool. And then uploaded the code.

```
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash 0x000000 blank_1MB.bin 
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash 0x100000 blank_1MB.bin
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash 0x200000 blank_1MB.bin 
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash 0x300000 blank_1MB.bin
```

This code will clear the memory of the esp8266.

Comment: `esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 erase_flash` is the easier way to clear the flash: https://github.com/espressif/esptool#erase-flash-erase_flash--erase-region

Comment: @MarcelStör Yes, this is the better way. Thankyou